# How to make infinity scroll on amp?

Tags: amp-html

How to make infinity scroll using amp? Using amp nextpage is not a solution because it comes from 1 source. And the condition like get data from 1 json, and each time scrolled it will display another 6 data.

I have tried both intersection observer and getBoundingClientRectAsync within amp-script to trigger button click when it appears on viewport to click load more, the log coming but the button not actually clicked.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your example and where the example fails.

Comment: I'm also interested, I already have a little experience with amp on wordpress. We can create this by helping each other.

Comment: I have created the Infinite Scroll plugin for the official AMP plugin for WordPress, try it and let me know if you need help, we provide support on WordPress Support forums.

https://github.com/milindmore22/amp-infinite-scroll

Comment: guys i put my example code in here, pls checkit, thankyou 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285932/amp-script-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-cli